# Gradient, scalar product and constraints

Tags: partial-derivative, constraints

I've a function $f=f(x,y,z)$ and a given constant vector $\vec A$.

Then, there is an equation  $\nabla f \cdot \vec A=\rm something$ that for me has a physical meaning.

I'd like to write the same equation in the case in which there is the constraint $x=yz$ and $f=x^2+y^2+z^2$ .

My problem is that I don't know how express the term $\nabla f \cdot \vec A$ in this case

Comment: That final sentence needs some re-writing for the question to be clear

Comment: thank you for the advice, I modified the question @FShrike

Comment: from $f(z, y, z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ you should be able to easily find $\nabla f$?

Comment: @SoboKevSpace I don't think it's so obvious because there is the constraint x=yz and I don't understand how to apply it. It's like $f(x(y,z),y,z)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraining $f$ doesn't affect its gradient, if you still allow $f$ to exist in three dimensional space. You *could* write a new function $g(y,z)=(yz)^2+y^2+z^2$ but this is now a two dimensional function, with two dimensional gradient, but its gradient would **not** agree with $f$'s gradient because it is in a different domain. Constraining just asks the question: what does $f$ look like in the domain where $x=yz$? But the gradient, its direction of steepest ascent, never changes - the constraint just means that a step in the direction of steepest ascent may be impossible, outside of the constraint. I suggest you research [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) for a demonstration of gradients and equality constraints; you'll see that we do not adjust the gradient of $f$ at all. The quantity $\nabla f\cdot\vec A$ is still the same! The function $f$ itself is unchanged, and the constraint merely yields the set of all points $f(yz,y,z)$ and **does not** yield the new function $g$!

You could perhaps visualise this as $f$ walking in the boundary surface, where $x=yz$, and the gradient stays unchanging, at times perhaps "tugging" $f$ outside of the constrained domain, at other times following it,... $\nabla f$ still acts in the same ways.

Comment: I'm reading your answer very carefully, thank you. My professor suggest us to use composite derivative to express that term, do you think is true?

Comment: Describe what you mean by composite derivative, @SimoBartz

Comment: I think something like the chain rule, professor didn't explain us in detail, it was just a comment

Comment: When I first considered your question, I considered finding $\nabla g$, and it is indeed possible to calculate things like $\partial/\partial(yz)$.... it's just that $\nabla g$ is a different gradient entirely, and lies in two dimensional space, which is clearly different from $f$. $\nabla g$ is, loosely speaking, $\nabla f$ if $f$ were cut off and it was impossible for $\nabla f$ to point outside of the constrained region... but this is now very different to the real $\nabla f$ itself

Comment: Also what is “that term”? @SimoBartz

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how express the term $\nabla f \cdot \vec A$ in this case. Professor told us: since x depends on y and z you can use composite derivative to express this term

Comment: To quote my answer - $\nabla f\cdot\vec A$ is the *same* as it always was @SimoBartz

Comment: Consider if we did in fact alter $f$ to be two dimensional, in the region of constraint, (which I have called the function $g$). $\vec A$ is three dimensional; $\nabla g$ is two-dimensional, so $\nabla g\cdot\vec A$ is...? It is completely undefined. If $A$ is not even inside the domain of constraint itself, then $\nabla g\cdot\vec A$ has no meaning whatsoever. Constraining a function does not mean you're actually *changing* the function; gradients remain the same. I strongly recommend looking at the intuition for lagrange multipliers @SimoBartz